# Backbone collections representing tree data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to load json data in form of a tree into Backbone Collection. I can't do this. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

My very simple model:

```
CTreeDataItem = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
});
CTreeDataItems = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: CTreeDataItem
});
```

And my load attepmt:

```
    var treeJs =
        [
            { id: "tvRoot", title: 'Root', cssClass: 'root',
                items: [
                    { id: "ti1", title: 'Item1', cssClass: 'item',
                        items: [
                            { id: "ti11", title: 'SubItem11', cssClass: 'subitem'},
                            { id: "ti12", title: 'SubItem12', cssClass: 'subitem'}]},
                    { id: "ti2", title: 'Item2', cssClass: 'item',},
                    { id: "ti3", title: 'Item3', cssClass: 'item', 
                        items: [
                            { id: "ti31", title: 'SubItem31', cssClass: 'subitem'},
                            { id: "ti32", title: 'SubItem32', cssClass: 'subitem'},
                            { id: "ti33", title: 'SubItem33', cssClass: 'subitem'}]}]
        }];
    this.TreeData = new CTreeDataItems();
    this.TreeData.add(treeJs);
```

Comment: What is the end result you're expecting, and where is it failing? Are you looking to have each node be represented as a model, with a collection of the child nodes on it?

Comment: "Are you looking to have each node be represented as a model, with a collection of the child nodes on it?" - this is exactly what i expected. The fail is that loading model only root element has been nested. So I have collection(1el)/model(root)/collection(1el)/model(root)/at least 4 -5lvls. I can't tell how deep and why it doesn't trigger an exception

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm trying to come up with an example of how to do that, will post it once I get past an exception that won't go away.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try representing the tree with `Model` as the node and each node containing a `Collection` of its child nodes:

```
var CTreeDataItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        if (Array.isArray(this.get('items'))) {
            this.set({items: new CTreeDataItemChildren(this.get('items'))});
        }
    }
});

// children collection
var CTreeDataItemChildren = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CTreeDataItem
});

// create
var treeData = new CTreeDataItemChildren(treeJs);

// access
treeData.at(0).get('items').at(1).get('title')
// returns "Item2"
```

---

**EDIT 2011-05-18:** If you want to flatten the tree and maintain a reference to the parent that each node had in the tree:

```
// flatten the tree outside of Backbone. Alternatively,
// you could override the constructor of the CTree collection
// to provide encapsulation
function flatten(parentID, arr) {
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var node = arr[i];
        node.parentID = parentID;
        out.push(node);
        if (Array.isArray(node.items))
            Array.prototype.push.apply(out, flatten(node.id, node.items));
        delete node.items;
    }
    return out;
}

// remove above code that would have provided nesting
var CTreeDataItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// children collection, as before 
var CTreeDataItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CTreeDataItem
});

// create
var treeData = new CTreeDataItemChildren(flatten('', treeJs));

// as before, but now there's the 'parentID' FK
treeData.at(3).get('parentID')
// returns "ti1"
```

Hope that's what you're after.

Comment: Well, there are different ways to flatten the tree structure. I rather go for relational db format where items have parentId. Or I can sort items and keep their indentation. I was only curious why I can't load tree data in json format creating nested collections and models from the same type.

Comment: The above code does load tree data into collections of models containing nested collections of models, so... not sure I follow. So what you're looking for is to flatten the tree, with child nodes put on the same axis as their parent, with some 'foreign key' referencing its parent it had in the ex-tree structure?

Comment: In fact I choose a 3rd solution. To reorganize my backend data in list format that. This is actually what your function flatten does but without its need :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Backbone.Model parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) method which is used to parse data before it gets passed to a model. You can use it to turn data on each level of your tree to Collections and Models representing items on these collections.

Then when saving you'd have to override the `toJSON` method on the Model to return the json representation of your data the same way you receive it. It is later on used by Backbone.sync to send the data back to the server. By default it returns only `_.clone` of your `Model.attributes` and you want all the Collections and CollectionModels in there as well.

All hail the backbone! :)